# Dynamic DNS updates via DHCP on CentOS

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I'm running mostly Ubuntu VMs in an vSphere cluster where a VLAN is managed by a DHCP and a Windows DNS. From the Ubuntu VMs I can update the DNS records in the Windows DNS to point the dynamic IP to its hostname (set in `/etc/hostname`) with `dhcp-identifier: mac` addition in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
  version: 2
```

But now I want to achieve the same DNS update functionality in a CentOS 7 VM, but can't get it to work. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. One needs to create `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and add `send fqdn.fqdn = gethostname();` to it. After that, a `dhclient -r; dhclient` sends the hostname in the DHCP* message.